# Can I tell how much of my memory is being used by JBoss at runtime?

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-management, jboss

In our production environment, JBoss 7.1.3 with Java 6 on Amazon Linux.  I’m trying to figure out how much of the allocated memory is actually being used at runtime by JBoss.  We start our JBoss with the following parameters (using max 10 GB of space) …

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx10240m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

When I run top it shows this …

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                       
13252 jboss     20   0 15.6g 9.5g  25m S 126.8 32.3 587:44.01 java
```

and Linux freemem shows …

```
[myuser@east1g ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         30104      13002      17102          0        162       2099
-/+ buffers/cache:      10739      19365
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Is there any way to tell how much of the allocated memory is actually being used by my JBoss process?

Comment: The amount of "real" RAM you are using can change (up or down) significantly over a short period of time so there's no way to give a specific answer.  You process has a virtual address space of 15.6g, of which 9.5g is currently resident in RAM.  The resident amount will change as load changes and as other processes request memory.

Comment: I just want to know it at a snapshot in time.  Are you saying it is impossible to figure that out?

Comment: You can take a snapshot. At the moment in your sample it occupies 9.5g.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use tools like jconsole, jvisualvm, jstat.. all of these applications show your current heap size (how much memory the jvm is taking from your os), and the actual jvm memory usage (the jvm can reserve more than it's actually using..)

For example, you can see how much memory is reserved, and how much memory is being used through jvisualvm

[image]